How to invoke Textract text analysis with trained adapters in C#?
In my lambda function I invoke Textract document analysis with the code below. In the results I get in the response, the queries defined in the adapter are not considered, only the ones i passed into the QueriesConfig field are taken into account.
How can I take advantage of the adapter training? Do I have to specify exactly the same queries defined in the adapter in the QueriesConfig request property? AWS documentation is not clear about this point.
Thanks in advance.
    var request = new AnalyzeDocumentRequest
    {
        Document = new Document
        {
            Bytes = file
        },
        FeatureTypes = new List<string> { 
            FeatureType.QUERIES
        },
        AdaptersConfig = new AdaptersConfig
        {
            Adapters = new List<Adapter>
            {
                new()
                {
                    AdapterId = OcrConstants.RegistrationAdapterId,
                    Version = "1"
                }
            }
        },
        QueriesConfig = RegistrationOcrStrategy.Queries
    };

    AnalyzeDocumentResponse? response = await _textractClient.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(request);

